# Can I access a database during startup in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have recently been working on a .NET Core web API. I have just attempted authentication using JWT, by following the guide on https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core.

All was going well until I had to replace the hard-coded username and passwords in the `GetIdentity` method with a DB query and realized I do not know how to access the DB from within this file!

The method I am referring to is shown in the link below on line 70.
https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider/blob/master/test/SimpleTokenProvider.Test/Startup.Auth.cs

My questions are as follows.

1. Can I access the database here? If so how?
2. Should this be where the GetIdentity method is, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can access the database! Code that runs in the `Configure` method can access any services that are added in the `ConfigureServices` method, including things like database contexts.

For example, if you have a simple Entity Framework context:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SimpleTokenProvider.Test.Models;

namespace SimpleTokenProvider.Test
{
    public class SimpleContext : DbContext
    {
        public SimpleContext(DbContextOptions<SimpleContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And you add it in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<SimpleContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase());
```

Then, you can access it when you are setting up the middleware:

```
var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<SimpleContext>();

app.UseSimpleTokenProvider(new TokenProviderOptions
{
    Path = "/api/token",
    Audience = "ExampleAudience",
    Issuer = "ExampleIssuer",
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
    IdentityResolver = (username, password) => GetIdentity(context, username, password)
});
```

And rewrite the `GetIdentity` method a little:

```
private Task<ClaimsIdentity> GetIdentity(SimpleContext context, string username, string password)
{
    // Access the database using the context
    // Here you'd need to do things like hash the password
    // and do a lookup to see if the user + password hash exists
}
```

I'm the author of the original sample. Sorry it wasn't clear initially! I tried to write the `IdentityResolver` delegate in a way that makes it easy to provide your own functionality -- like integrating with your own database (as above), or hooking it up to ASP.NET Core Identity. Of course, you're free to throw away my code and do something better, too. :)

Comment: If you're just adding JWT to aspnet identity, you may pass the signinmanager instead of the dbcontext:
    var userManager = app.ApplicationServices
        .GetService(typeof(UserManager<ApplicationUser>))

Comment: @xcud That's exactly what I'm trying to do but get an error " Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`", what am I missing here?

Comment: Should update the sample or add this concept in comments, this was driving me crazy for hours! Thank you for your answer!

Comment: This does not work for scoped services. If you've used `AddDbContext` with Entity Framework then your DB service is scoped. Check out my answer for a solution.

Comment: @xcud you need to add Identity to the services, for example services.AddIdentity<User, Role>() will add User and Role so you are able to use throughout your application

Answer (score 17):

On .NET CORE 2.1, just pass the context as an argument to the Configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, YourDbContext context, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
        //do whatever you want with the context here...
}
```

> Adding services to the **service container** makes them available within
>   the app and in the **Configure** method. The services are resolved via
>   dependency injection or from ApplicationServices.

Comment: This is the actual and simplest answer, provided you have registered your `DbContext` with `DI` upfront or implicitly with `AddDbContext`. Working at least from `.net core 2.1`as stated in this answer (Didn't check it, works with 3.0 prev)

Comment: May I ask if you registered a service as scoped, can you still access it within the `Configure` method or only transients and singletons work here?

Comment: @jegtugado is supposed to work. Btw AddDbContext adds as scoped

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer does not work for scoped services ([scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes) services are created per request, if you are using Entity Framework and adding the context with `AddDbContext` then [this is the case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#entity-framework-contexts)).

You can use scoped services in startup as follows ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#call-services-from-main)):

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
        var myDbContext = services.GetService<MyDbContext>();
    }
}
```

or pass it in the argument of the `Configure` method as shown in the answer of
juanora

Comment: I think this is the recommended way to consume scoped services in singletons and services, reference sample code: [consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong on some other level but the solution I found is to create a scope.

I passed the app instead of the ctx in GetIdentity, then in GetIdentity using a scope:

```
using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope()) {
    if (serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<YourAppDbContext>() != null) 
    {
      var ctx = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<YourAppDbContext>();

      if (AnAuthenticateMethodHereMaybe(ctx, username, password)) {
        return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsIdentity(new 
GenericIdentity(username, "Token"), new Claim[] { }));
      }
    }
  }
```