# Is it possible to set Cookie ExpireTimeSpan by getting the value from DbContext in Startup.cs?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I have a .NET 5 application that uses `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` for User Authentication and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to store values into the DB.

This is how my `ConfigureServices()` in `Startup.cs` looks like (I removed some parts for simplicity):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ApplicationDbContext
        services
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationHelper.GetDecryptedConnectionString());
            });

        // Customer Settings Service Injection
        services.AddScoped<CustomerSettingsService>();

        // Add Identity
        services
            .AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>();

        // Cookie Expiration
        services
            .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
    }
```

Here I add the `ApplicationDbContext`, I inject the `CustomerSettingsService` which uses the `ApplicationDbContext` to obtain/store values from/to the DB, I add `AddDefaultIdentity` and I provide 15 minutes as `ExpireTimeSpan` to the cookie so the user is logged out in case of inactivity.

Now I would like to use the `CustomerSettingsService` to obtain the value for `ExpireTimeSpan` from the database, so how can I do this?

I tried by building the ServiceProvider (`services.BuildServiceProvider()`) and then obtaining the `CustomerSettingsService` and calling the `Get()` method, but I get a warning saying: `"Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'"`

Then, I moved that part to the `Configure()` method, I can get the service and the value from the DB correctly, but then I can't/don't know how access the `ConfigureApplicationCookie()` part to set the `ExpireTimeSpan` value.

I feel like I'm in a chicken/egg dilemma! I'm sure this is a common use case and there must be a way to solve it. Maybe it is possible to change the `ExpireTimeSpan` outside of the `Startup.cs`?

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Im not very familiar with Asp.net Identity but are you looking for a way to access the db in Startup.cs ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728623/can-i-access-a-database-during-startup-in-asp-net-core/51176775

Comment: Hey thanks, but the problem is not *only* accessing the db in Startup.cs... I already tried (and succeeded) using that post! 

As you can see in the post, when it calls `var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<SimpleContext>();` that's already inside the `Configure()` method, and that's the part where I can't access/assign the `ExpireTimeSpan` anymore.

I appreciate your effort anyway!